# Python - checking if a word from a list is a substring of another string

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def find_word_list(query, word_dict):
    for word in word_dict:
        if word in query:
            print("true")
        else:
            print("false")
    return
```

If I call the function as follows, it would just print an empty list.

```
query1 = ["donaldtrump"]
dict1 = ["donald", "trump"]

find_word_list(query1, dict1)
```

The result I expected:

```
true
true
```

Here's what I actually got

```
false
false
```

both 'donald' and 'trump' are the substrings of a given query, 'donaldtrump'. How should I fix the code?

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out myself. The problem was, that the `query1` variable is a list type, so it was `["donaldtrump"]` not `"donaldtrump"`.

After changing the variable type to string, it now works as I expected.

Comment: Well.. stackoverflow isn't a debug service, but since you serviced yourself I don't know what to do now.. have an upvote AND a downvote lol